# How to write some amounts to a File?

Tags: writetofile

I'm doing this program for a class; I have a listbox  with 4 choices that are counted each time they're selected,and i'm supposed to write out the results to an out.File so that they can then be retrieved and displayed when asked to.

[Here's an image,so you can see what i mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXPNM.png)

Here's the code i got for the file part so far:

```
'declare a streamwriter variable
    Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter

    'open file for output
    outFile = IO.File.CreateText("Commercials.txt")

    'write to file
    For intIndex As Integer = 0 To lstCommercial.Items.Count - 1
        outFile.WriteLine(lstCommercial.Items(intIndex))
    Next intIndex

    'close th efile
    outFile.Close()
```

So my problem is this,i can get everything to work except for it to write the totals to the file,with the result of not displaying. How do i go about doing this? What am i doing wrong in any case?

Comment: Is lstCommercial.Items a Collection object? or is it an Array?

Comment: A Collection object i believe, i have it in the form's load part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what lstCommercial.Items is.
If it is a Collection object, then you can get the index of an item using the following:

```
outFile.WriteLine(lstCommercial.Items.Item(intIndex))
```

If it is an array, then instead of using the Count property to find the length, you should rather use GetUpperBound(0) to find the last index:

```
For intIndex As Integer = 0 To lstCommercial.Items.GetUpperBound(0)
```

I have very little experience in Visual Basic so I am probably wrong, but I have just gathered this from reading [Arrays in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) and [Collection Object (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb7y698k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Also, looking at the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you may need to 'Flush' the buffer to the file before closing it:

```
outFile.Flush()
'close the file
outFile.Close()
```